# Ansible - if lookup env is empty, default into a different variable

Tags: ansible

as title says, is there a way to use two variables if one is empty and set another var?

can I use something like this?

example, if i have an Ansible variable server=5015
and env server is empty

```
SERVER_NAME: "{{ lookup('env','server') | default({{ server }}) }}"
```

If lookup env var server is empty, then set a variable version of server
will this work?

Answer (score 2):

You never nest `{{...}}` markers. You would write something like:

```
SERVER_NAME: "{{ lookup('env','server') | default(server, true) }}"
```

Here, the second argument to the `default` filter causes `default` to use the replacement if the result of the `lookup()` is empty (otherwise, `default` only works if the previous item is undefined).

This assumes that `server` is the name of a variable that is available in your current scope.

Comment: so in this case this case if i have an Ansible variable server=5015 and env lookup server is empty
 default(server) server will be 5015? why is there a true?

Comment: I answered that explicitly. Without that second argument, `default()` will not change an empty value (only an undefined value). Please see [the documentation](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.1.x/templates/#jinja-filters.default) for details.